# Format a write-protected pendrive in Linux

Tags: linux, usb-drive

I have a boot pen drive with the Lubuntu ISO and I wanted to format it.
I can not delete files from the pendrive because they are read-only.

I tried to format it as follows:

```
#umount  /dev/sdb1

#mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1
mkfs.fat 4.0 (2016-05-06)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb1: Read-only file system
```

Could someone helpe me?

- I've checked answers to similar questions to my own and none have solved.

Comment: Please add to the question how exactly that pen is write protected. Is it a physical switch?

Comment: umount the pen ; then `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4096`

Answer (score 1):

You can completely remove a filesystem with `wipefs`.

In your case (as `root`):

```
wipefs --all /dev/sdb
```

But, just so we're clear on this, **make sure you are wiping the correct drive**. In other words, double and triple check that `dev/sdb` is indeed the correct drive, so that you don't delete something else. You have been warned!

Anyway, after that, try to format the drive again.

**[Here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/wipefs.8.html)** is a link to the `wipefs` manpage for Ubuntu. And here is **[another link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media#Using_dd)** from the excellent Arch wiki:

> To restore the USB drive as an empty, usable storage device after
>   using the Arch ISO image, the iso9660 filesystem signature needs to be
>   removed by running `wipefs --all /dev/sdx` as root, before
>   repartitioning and reformating the USB drive.

Comment: I did it but it did not work.
wipefs --all /dev/sdb1 --force;
umount  /dev/sdb1;
mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1;
The data on the pendrive is still there when I remount it.

Comment: wipefs: error: /dev/sde: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system